# Pysftp. Get files based on Modification Date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysftp

I'm trying to write a script to retrieve files from an SFTP server if the modification date is less than 24 hours.
This is my attempt so far:

```
cnopts = sftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
s = sftp.Connection(host=host, username=username, password=password, port=port, cnopts=cnopts)
s.cwd(r"/Outbox")
for attr in s.listdir_attr("ENTOUT_709_Payers_20170802024203.csv"):
    print(attr)
```

Here are the results...

```
?rw-rw-rw- 1 0 0 8339 02 Aug 02:42 ENTOUT_709_Payers_20170802024203.csv
```

How would I retrieve `"02 Aug 02:42"` in the format of `%Y%M%d?`

Answer (score 1):

I have a substitute for it:

```
def unix2human(unixtime, fmt = "%Y-%m-%d"):
    try:
        return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(unixtime)).strftime(fmt)
    except Exception as e:
        log.warning("Failed to convert unixtime string '{}' :: {}".format(unixtime, e))
        return None
```

So your code will look like:

```
for attr in s.listdir_attr("ENTOUT_709_Payers_20170802024203.csv"):
    print(unix2human(attr.st_mtime))
```

where *st_mtime* is the built-in pysftp method

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the date string you get back from the ftp directory listing like this:

```
import datetime
input_date = "02 Aug 02:42"
parsed_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date,"%d %b %H:%M").replace(year=2017)
print(f"{parsed_date:%Y%m%d}")
```

Output is `20170802`.

Comment: Just noted that this will fail for leap days, e.g. Feb 29, since year defaults to 1900. Maybe add the year to the `input_date` string instead of using `replace` to overcome this.